# Eloquent Javascript: Higher Order Functions example

Tags: javascript

```
  function reduceAncestors(person, f, defaultValue) {
    function valueFor(person) {
      if (person == null)
        return defaultValue;
      else
        return f(person, valueFor(byName[person.mother]),
                       valueFor(byName[person.father]));
  }
    return valueFor(person);
  }


  function sharedDNA(person, fromMother, fromFather) {
    if (person.name == "Pauwels van Haverbeke")
      return 1;
    else
      return (fromMother + fromFather) / 2;
  }
  var ph = byName["Philibert Haverbeke"];
  console.log(reduceAncestors(ph, sharedDNA, 0) / 4);
  // → 0.00049
```

I am having a lot of trouble understanding this example from Eloquent Javascript. This is the example at the end of the Higher Order Functions Chapter (chpt 5), under the heading "Great-Great-Great..." I don't see where fromMother and fromFather are getting their values. I think that they are referring to valueFor(byName[person.mother] and valueFor(byName[person.father]), but I don't see how or when the "valueFor" functions ever retrieve an actual number value from the data (note that I obviously didn't include the data in this post, nor did I include the byName function). Thanks in advance for any help!

Answer (score 3):

`reduceAncestors(ph, sharedDNA, 0) / 4)` passes the `sharedDNA` function as the second argument.

It gets assigned to `f` here:

```
function reduceAncestors(person, f, defaultValue)
```

`f` gets called here:

```
f(person, valueFor(byName[person.mother]), valueFor(byName[person.father]));
```

… where you can see the second and third arguments which get assigned to `fromMother` and `fromFather`:

```
function sharedDNA(person, fromMother, fromFather) {
```

Comment: I can trace them back to where f assigns them values, but why aren't those values zero? When the recursive call gets to the oldest generation, the mother and father will be assigned the default value of 0, right? So then, (0 + 0) / 2 = 0. I know I'm missing something, but I'm not sure what.

Answer (score 2):

You could see it as follows:

First, `f` and `sharedDNA` are the same during the execution of this particular call.

Secondly, `valueOf` can return the following values:

- 0, when `person == null`
- 1, when `person == "Pauwels van Haverbeke"` (see `shareDNA`)
- Another value between 0 and 1 by the average of previously calculated values: `(fromMother + fromFather) / 2`

So if "Pauwels van Haverbeke" is not found in the ancestry of "Philibert Haverbeke" then the final value will be 0.

But if "Pauwels van Haverbeke" is found as an immediate parent of "Philibert Haverbeke" then the final value, before division by 4 in the `console.log`, is

```
(0 + 1) / 2 = 1/2
```

If "Pauwels van Haverbeke" is found as a grand-parent, then the final value is

```
((0 + 0) / 2 + (0 + 1) / 2) / 2 = 1/4
```

More generally, if he is found n generations back, the final value is

```
2 ^ (-n)
```

Now 2 ^ (-11) happens to be 0.0004882813..., so your (rounded) result 0.00049 means *Pauwels van Haverbeke* is an ancestor of *Philibert Haverbeke*, 9 generations earlier, taking into account that there is a division by 4 in `console.log`.