# Chapter 5 Eloquent Java Example: Higher order functions

Tags: javascript, higher-order-functions

I am creating a duplicate of ["Eloquent Javascript: Higher Order Functions example"](https://stackoverflow.com/questions/25125148/eloquent-javascript-higher-order-functions-example?answertab=active#tab-top) because I don't feel the question received a satisfactory answer. In the following code, where does the actual value for fromMother and fromFather come from. I can trace them back to where f assigns them values, but why aren't those values zero? When the recursive call gets to the oldest generation, the mother and father will be assigned the default value of 0, right? So then, (0 + 0) / 2 = 0. I know I'm missing something, but I'm not sure what.

```js
 function reduceAncestors(person, f, defaultValue) {
    function valueFor(person) {
      if (person == null)
        return defaultValue;
      else
        return f(person, valueFor(byName[person.mother]),
                       valueFor(byName[person.father]));
  }
    return valueFor(person);
  }


  function sharedDNA(person, fromMother, fromFather) {
    if (person.name == "Pauwels van Haverbeke")
      return 1;
    else
      return (fromMother + fromFather) / 2;
  }
  var ph = byName["Philibert Haverbeke"];
  console.log(reduceAncestors(ph, sharedDNA, 0) / 4);
  // → 0.00049
```

Comment: Voting to close as a duplicate. Just because the other question didn't get a good answer doesn't mean we need a second question. It's better to draw attention to the original, in the form of a bounty or an answer of your own.

Comment: According to the site instructions, you're not supposed to use answers to ask questions?

Comment: You can ask for clarification on [Quentin's answer](http://stackoverflow.com/a/25125207/7469) if you don't understand it, although I think it answers your question clearly.

Comment: I disagree, it's a pretty low quality answer. Regardless you shouldn't make a dupe question.

Comment: @Loktar I hope you are going to post a better one! ;-)

Comment: I have added a new answer on the other question. I think it is what you are looking for.

Comment: Thanks trincot. I appreciate the help :)